# DSPUSRPRF UPCHGD field

Tags: ibm-midrange

I'm checking the user profiles deactivated in the past, running DSPUSRPRF *OUTFILE it appears inside the filed UPCHGD (Change date) a recent date in 2021 while the user has no more connected since 2017.
What can be the reason and how can I avoid this date to be updated?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The change date on an object can be updated by a number of things. Actual uses, restores, in the case of a user profile, if some other job uses the user profile for something, etc. In the case of a user profile, it is not just logins.

Answer (score 0):

when a user logs in, UPCHGD and UPCHGT are updated.

get the UPCHGD and UPCHGT from the DSPUSRPRF OUTFILE.  Then run the DSPLOG command for 10 seconds or so around that date and time.

```
DSPLOG PERIOD((095300 092721) (095400 092721))
```

You should see some login messages that match the the UPCHGD and UPCHGT.

Comment: Hello, the user has: last used date 02 March 2020, then it has been disabled but running DSPUSRPRF

Comment: it appears change date 15 July 2021, this is strange for me